# I get different file size from the original file when I download a file that I have uploaded to Google Drive in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-drive-api

**Hello Everyone!**

My goal is to upload the database (`RealmJS`) that I have stored on my device storage to Google Drive with `Google Drive API V3`, to do that I've already installed a few node_modules like `react-native-fs`, and `@react-native-community/google-signin`.

The database upload process is going well but I don't know what method should actually be used to upload a file, I've looked everywhere, and what I found there is a method `Buffer`, `new Blob()`, and `new FormData()`.

I have tried these three methods, two of them `Buffer` and `new Blob()` produce a different file size from the original file, and the result from the `new FormData()` method only raises network errors even though my network is fine

I'm still new to `Google Drive API V3` and I have no idea to solve this issue even I read the documentation I can't understand it because my English is bad. It would be helpful to both me and other readers if you have an idea for this problem included with an explanation of the code you posted.

**And this is my code**

```js
import fs from 'react-native-fs';
import {GoogleSignin} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

/**
 * Here I have logged in to my own Google account so I just need to take the token
 */
async function backupDatabase() {
  const {accessToken} = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
  const noneMime = 'application/octet-stream';

  /**
   * Using "uploadType=resumable" because my file size is larger than 5MB
   */
  const requestUpload = await fetch(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': noneMime,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'mydb.realm',
        mimeType: noneMime,
        description: 'Backup Database',
        parents: ['appDataFolder'],
      }),
    },
  );

  if (requestUpload.ok) {
    const resumableUploadURL = requestUpload.headers.get('location');

    /**
     * I read the file, it's ".realm" ext soo i using
     * "base64" encode
     */
    const myFile = await fs.readFile(myPathFile, 'base64');
    
    /**
     * This is how i upload the file with this method
     */
    const fileBlob = new Blob([myFile], {type: noneMime});
    const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(myFile, 'base64');
    /**
     * This one is always failing a network failed even
     * my network is fine
     */
    const fileFormData = new FormData();
    fileFormData.append('file', fileBlob);

    const uploadDatabase = await fetch(resumableUploadURL, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      },

      /**
       * At this stage, I don't understand what method to use?
       * You guys have any idea? Is that "Buffer", "Blob", or "FormData"?
       */
      body: fileBlob, // OR "fileBuffer" OR "fileFormData" 
    });

    const responseUpload = await uploadDatabase.json();
    console.log(responseUpload);
  }
}
```

Comment: Really not into react, but you are reading your file as a base64 string, so when you do `new Blob([myFile])`, what you really are doing is to create a new text file from this base64 string encoded in utf-8: This is not your original file at all. Not sure what this `Blob` implementation accepts as input, but you'd need to build one from the buffer directly (don't pass encoding option to `readFile`)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the answer :), but if I didn't past encoding it will throw an Error because `readFile` in `react-native-fs` has default encoding that is an `utf-8` so I can't read file `Realm` in `utf-8`

Comment: And you can't have it return a Buffer? Once again I don't know react at all, but that's the default of `readFile` and if they removed it, they messed up badly.

Comment: @Kaiido No, It's not returning a Buffer, not like `fs` in NodeJS

Comment: And what is your `fileBuffer` holding? The result of parsing that base64 string to a Buffer? If so, try to build the Blob from that instead. Though having to encode+decode sounds silly to me...

Comment: Yeah, `base64` to `Buffer` and I think it's just like an Image I can read it as `base64` normally, it's that correct? `If so, try to build the Blob from that instead.` you mean? Create `new Blob()` again after `Buffer.from()`

Comment: I guess so, now try to create your `fileBlob` from that `fileBuffer` (maybe `new Blob([fileBuffer]))`)  and upload that.

Comment: I try your method, I got a different response, it's telling me the file size that I have uploaded, `{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "96c88cb0-c97e-46b4-b3e4-7aef677ce633", "lastModified": undefined, "offset": 0, "size": 1129310, "type": "application/octet-stream"}}`, but when I download that file the size only 203 bytes it's still different, maybe I am wrong using `API .get() file by Id`? But the Docs didn't give an example :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this issue, I am wrong when using `API` [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) where the wrong is I didn't pass query `alt=media` into the URL and it's should be `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?alt=media"`. [See docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive)

In the code above I am using `fileBuffer` NOT `fileBlob` or `fileFromData` as the `request body` and that's it, my `Realm` that I have uploaded it's totally normal and I can open it normally

Thanks to [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) for helping me a lot :D